# How to create a CPU spike with a bash command

Tags: linux, bash, load, cpu

I want to create a near 100% load on a Linux machine.  It's quad core system and I want all cores going full speed.  Ideally, the CPU load would last a designated amount of time and then stop.  I'm hoping there's some trick in bash.  I'm thinking some sort of infinite loop.

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/443406/how-can-i-produce-high-cpu-load-on-a-linux-server

Answer (score 330, accepted):

You can also do

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
```

To run more of those to put load on more cores, try to fork it:

```
fulload() { dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null & }; fulload; read; killall dd
```

Repeat the command in the curly brackets as many times as the number of threads you want to produce (here 4 threads). 
Simple enter hit will stop it (just make sure no other dd is running on this user or you kill it too).

Comment: dd deals more with I/O than with CPU usage

Comment: This actually worked the best for my situation.  It also worked in Cygwin.  For some reason, the other solutions wouldn't quite spike the CPU.  Adding a count and making four processes in parallel worked perfectly.  It spiked the CPU at 100% in top and then back down to zero without any help.  Just four lines of code and a "wait".

Comment: Reading from `/dev/zero` and writing to `/dev/null` is not a very good  load generator - you have to run a lot of them to generate significant load. Better to do something like `dd if=/dev/urandom | bzip2 -9 >> /dev/null`. `/dev/urandom` requires significantly more effort to generate output, and `bzip2` will expend a lot of effort trying to compress it, so the overall CPU usage is a lot higher than  "fill a block with zeros, and then throw it away".

Comment: Use `jobs -p | xargs kill` to only kill the processes you have created.

Comment: @twalberg, you should make your comment into an answer.

Comment: Works great. In CentOS 7, i had to substitute 'killall dd' with 'pkill -e ^dd'

Comment: instead of "bzip2" you can try "pbzip2" - it is multithreaded and will load all cores.

Comment: @twalberg, compressing from /dev/urandom on my system generates more load for dd than it does for bzip2. So, still probably not a very good load generator. A solution can be to chain the bzip2 commands so that the data random is reused and dd makes up a relatively small fraction of total cpu:  dd if=/dev/urandom | bzip2 -9 | bzip2 -9 | bzip2 -9 | bzip2 -9 >> /dev/null

Comment: @RoG That's not inconsistent with the OP's requirement - they only asked for a way to make the CPUs busy, with no specification of whether it's kernel-mode or user-mode activity. `dd` from `/dev/urandom` will create high kernel-mode activity, and attempting to compress that data contributes a user-mode factor. Busy CPUs are busy....

Comment: Thanks @dimba and @twalberg ... the solution for me was `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null` which ran my cpu at 100%

Comment: is this possible for windows?

Comment: If all CPUs are at 100% load in `top`, how is this solution "not a very good load generator"?  Is there some other metric that should be measured?

Comment: For people with many CPUs to stress, I found that `cat /dev/zero | pbzip2` worked much better than `/dev/urandom` -- urandom was blocking on the apparently single-threaded generation of random data, while /dev/zero can produce zeroes much (much) faster.  Even if it trivially compresses, having to do that work (along with distributing 900kB blocks of zeroes) produces nearly arbitrarily large CPU load.

Answer (score 425):

I use [stress](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stress) for this kind of thing, you can tell it how many cores to max out.. it allows for stressing memory and disk as well.

Example to stress 2 cores for 60 seconds

`stress --cpu 2 --timeout 60`

Comment: On Fedora, `sudo yum install stress`

Comment: You need to `EPEL` repo for CentOS `wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`

Comment: [`brew`](http://brew.sh/) `install stress` on OS X. Also for some reason I had to specify 8 cores on a quad-core MBPr

Comment: @bfred.it Your cores may utilize hyperthreading, effectively doubling your amount of cores (4 physical and 4 virtual cores). You'll also want to stress the virtual ones for a full load test.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install stress` on debian based systems, for completeness. Used this to test a cooling mod on the [Intel i7 NUC Kit](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/nuc-kit-nuc5i7ryh.html).

Comment: CentOS 7: #wget dag.wieers.com/redhat/el7/en/x86_64/dag/RPMS/stress-1.0.2-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 173):

I think this one is simpler. Open Terminal and type the following and press Enter.

```
yes > /dev/null &
```

To fully utilize modern CPUs, one line is not enough, you may need to repeat the command to exhaust all the CPU power.

To end all of this, simply put

```
killall yes
```

The idea was originally found [here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/10/02/stress-test-mac-cpu/), although it was intended for Mac users, but this should work for *nix as well.

Comment: +1 Works like a charm, thank you! **Worth adding**: this command will max out one hyperthread per cpu core. So a dual core cpu (each core having 2 threads) will get a total load of 25% per `yes` command (assuming the system was otherwise idle).

Comment: Just to add to this, Each iteration of this command adds 25 percent load on the CPU (Android) up to 4 iterations and the rest have no effect (even in terms of clock rate).

Comment: If you have multiple terminal sessions or tmux tabs, it's simple to run `yes > /dev/null`, then CTRL+C it when you're done

Comment: Note that, if you are looking to push as many Watts as possible through the CPU, this command may not be enough. Use the "stress" command instead. I thought there was something wrong with my machine because I was seeing only 12 W (despite 100% CPU load), but "stress" gives me the full 15 W I expected. (i7-6500U)

Comment: Addendum: actually, the best solution (power-wise) seems to be the "for loop" by Marian. I even reach 16 W by running it twice in parallel.

Answer (score 47):

Although I'm late to the party, this post is among the top results in the google search "generate load in linux".

The result marked as solution could be used to generate a system load, i'm preferring to use `sha1sum /dev/zero` to impose a load on a cpu-core.

The idea is to calculate a hash sum from an infinite datastream (eg. /dev/zero, /dev/urandom, ...) this process will try to max out a cpu-core until the process is aborted.
To generate a load for more cores, multiple commands can be piped together.

eg. generate a 2 core load: 
`sha1sum /dev/zero | sha1sum /dev/zero`

Comment: Seeing, this to be better than dd for CPU load. I get max cpu load of 44% on dd (6 times) and 86%+ on sha1sum . Thx~!

Answer (score 40):

To load 3 cores for 5 seconds:

```
seq 3 | xargs -P0 -n1 timeout 5 yes > /dev/null
```

This results in high kernel (sys) load from the many write() system calls.

If you prefer mostly userland cpu load:

```
seq 3 | xargs -P0 -n1 timeout 5 md5sum /dev/zero
```

If you just want the load to continue until you press Ctrl-C:

```
seq 3 | xargs -P0 -n1 md5sum /dev/zero
```

Comment: Is this possible from tinycore?  xargs: invalid option -- 'P'

Comment: nice native option

Comment: for some reason this command `timeout 5 md5sum /dev/zero` always returns an exit code of 124, which causes issues with scripts that have strict exit codes enabled.

Answer (score 32):

One core (doesn't invoke external process):

```
while true; do true; done
```

Two cores:

```
while true; do /bin/true; done
```

The latter only makes both of mine go to ~50% though...

This one will make both go to 100%:

```
while true; do echo; done
```

Comment: on echo, we loose the access to linux.  how to put that 3rd command in background ?

Comment: Why does echo make all cpu cores to 100%?

Comment: @HaoyuanGe All the cpus are 100% only when echoing "nothing". Replace the do echo; with do echo "some very very long string"; to see <100% on the cpus. So, I believe, echoing nothing has lot less jumps and hence more code to execute (because of while true;) the cores are ~100% busy

Comment: If you want to keep a server responsive whilst running such a test, do it in a separate shell (another tmux/screen window, or ssh session), and renice that shell first, e.g. in bash: `renice 19 -p $$`. It'll still max the CPUs, but won't impinge on other processes.

Comment: this code `while true; do /bin/true; done
` good but  When one  I add that the CPU speed increases `while true; do /bin/true & echo "b"; done
`

Answer (score 19):

An infinite loop is the idea I also had. A freaky-looking one is:

```
while :; do :; done
```

(`:` is the same as `true`, does nothing and exits with zero)

You can call that in a subshell and run in the background. Doing that `$num_cores` times should be enough. After sleeping the desired time you can kill them all, you get the PIDs with `jobs -p` (hint: `xargs`)

Comment: Very nice. Minimalistic and pure bash. Loads cpu nicely.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a program that you can download [Here](http://weather.ou.edu/~apw/projects/stress/)

Install easily on your Linux system

```
./configure
make
make install
```

and launch it in a simple command line

```
stress -c 40
```

to stress all your CPUs (however you have) with 40 threads each running a complex `sqrt` computation on a ramdomly generated numbers.

You can even define the timeout of the program

```
stress -c 40 -timeout 10s
```

unlike the proposed solution with the `dd` command, which deals essentially with `IO` and therefore doesn't really overload your system because working with data.

The stress program really overloads the system because dealing with computation.

Comment: There is already an answer above for the `stress` command. As that answer says, you can just install it via yum/apt/etc.

Comment: Website not in good condition (503 Forbidden) but is available on the repos :)

Answer (score 13):

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

**This fork bomb will cause havoc to the CPU and will likely crash your computer.**

Comment: It'll help if I make it easier to read

fork_bomb() {
  fork_bomb | fork_bomb &
};

forkbomb

Comment: That one fails on the "last a designated amount of time and then stop" criterion ;)

Comment: looks like a bunch of smiley faces.

Comment: This fork bomb crashed my computer, I had to do a hard power cycle.

Comment: From: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-bash-fork-bomb/
WARNING! These examples may crash your computer if executed.
"Once a successful fork bomb has been activated in a system it may not be possible to resume normal operation without rebooting the system as the only solution to a fork bomb is to destroy all instances of it."

Answer (score 11):

I would split the thing in 2 scripts :

infinite_loop.bash :

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ] ; do
    # Force some computation even if it is useless to actually work the CPU
    echo $((13**99)) 1>/dev/null 2>&1
done
```

cpu_spike.bash :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Either use environment variables for NUM_CPU and DURATION, or define them here
for i in `seq ${NUM_CPU}` : do
    # Put an infinite loop on each CPU
    infinite_loop.bash &
done

# Wait DURATION seconds then stop the loops and quit
sleep ${DURATION}
killall infinite_loop.bash
```

Answer (score 9):

to increase load or consume CPU 100% or X%

```
sha1sum /dev/zero &
```

on some system this will increase the load in slots of X%, in that case you have to run the same command multiple time.

then you can see CPU uses by typing command

```
top
```

to release the load

```
killall sha1sum
```

Answer (score 8):

```
cat /dev/urandom > /dev/null
```

Comment: Add some comment as well, it helps.

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash
duration=120    # seconds
instances=4     # cpus
endtime=$(($(date +%s) + $duration))
for ((i=0; i<instances; i++))
do
    while (($(date +%s) < $endtime)); do :; done &
done
```

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to install additional software, you may use a compression utility which utilizes all CPU cores automatically. For example, xz:

```
 cat /dev/zero | xz -T0 > /dev/null
```

This takes infinite stream of dummy data from /dev/zero and compresses it using all cores available in the system.

Answer (score 4):

I've used `bc` (*binary calculator*), asking them for PI with a big lot of decimals.

```
$ for ((i=0;i<$NUMCPU;i++));do
    echo 'scale=100000;pi=4*a(1);0' | bc -l &
    done ;\
    sleep 4; \
    killall bc
```

with NUMCPU (under Linux):

```
$ NUMCPU=$(grep $'^processor\t*:' /proc/cpuinfo |wc -l)
```

This method is strong but seem *system friendly*, as I've never crashed a system using this.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]
do
        #Your code goes here
done
```

Comment: Eh, no. Sleeping is not that kind of task that puts lots of laod on the cpu `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

I went through the Internet to find something like it and found this very handy cpu hammer script.

```
#!/bin/sh

# unixfoo.blogspot.com

if [ $1 ]; then
    NUM_PROC=$1
else
    NUM_PROC=10
fi

for i in `seq 0 $((NUM_PROC-1))`; do
    awk 'BEGIN {for(i=0;i<10000;i++)for(j=0;j<10000;j++);}' &
done
```

Comment: Does it really need to be that long ? I like one-liners best for this kind of task…

Comment: The if-then-else clause can be replaced by: `NUM_PROC=${1:-10}`.

Answer (score 2):

Using examples mentioned here, but also help from IRC, I developed my own CPU stress testing script. It uses a subshell per thread and the endless loop technique. You can also specify the number of threads and the amount of time interactively.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Simple CPU stress test script

# Read the user's input
echo -n "Number of CPU threads to test: "
read cpu_threads
echo -n "Duration of the test (in seconds): "
read cpu_time

# Run an endless loop on each thread to generate 100% CPU
echo -e "\E[32mStressing ${cpu_threads} threads for ${cpu_time} seconds...\E[37m"
for i in $(seq ${cpu_threads}); do
    let thread=${i}-1
    (taskset -cp ${thread} $BASHPID; while true; do true; done) &
done

# Once the time runs out, kill all of the loops
sleep ${cpu_time}
echo -e "\E[32mStressing complete.\E[37m"
kill 0
```

Comment: getting error "line 14: taskset: command not found" on your script! any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Utilizing ideas here, created code which exits automatically after a set duration, don't have to kill processes --

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Usage : ./killproc_ds.sh 6 60  (6 threads for 60 secs)"

# Define variables
NUM_PROCS=${1:-6} #How much scaling you want to do
duration=${2:-20}    # seconds

function infinite_loop {
endtime=$(($(date +%s) + $duration))
while (($(date +%s) < $endtime)); do
    #echo $(date +%s)
    echo $((13**99)) 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    $(dd if=/dev/urandom count=10000 status=none| bzip2 -9 >> /dev/null) 2>&1 >&/dev/null
done
echo "Done Stressing the system - for thread $1"
}


echo Running for duration $duration secs, spawning $NUM_PROCS threads in background
for i in `seq ${NUM_PROCS}` ;
do
# Put an infinite loop
    infinite_loop $i  &
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to test the performance of cryptographic algorithms.

```
openssl speed -multi 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This does a trick for me:

```
bash -c 'for (( I=100000000000000000000 ; I>=0 ; I++ )) ; do echo $(( I+I*I )) & echo $(( I*I-I )) & echo $(( I-I*I*I )) & echo $(( I+I*I*I )) ; done' &>/dev/null
```

and it uses nothing except bash.

Answer (score 1):

To enhance dimba's answer and provide something more pluggable (because i needed something similar).  I have written the following using the dd load-up concept :D

It will check current cores, and create that many dd threads.
Start and End core load with *Enter*

```
#!/bin/bash

load_dd() {
    dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
}

fulload() {
    unset LOAD_ME_UP_SCOTTY
    export cores="$(grep proc /proc/cpuinfo -c)"
    for i in $( seq 1 $( expr $cores - 1 ) )
      do
    export LOAD_ME_UP_SCOTTY="${LOAD_ME_UP_SCOTTY}$(echo 'load_dd | ')"
  done
        export LOAD_ME_UP_SCOTTY="${LOAD_ME_UP_SCOTTY}$(echo 'load_dd &')"
    eval ${LOAD_ME_UP_SCOTTY}
}

echo press return to begin and stop fullload of cores
  read
  fulload
  read
  killall -9 dd
```

Answer (score 1):

Dimba's `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null` is definitely correct, but also worth mentioning is verifying maxing the cpu to 100% usage. You can do this with

```
ps -axro pcpu | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

This asks for ps output of a 1-minute average of the cpu usage by each process, then sums them with awk. While it's a 1 minute average, ps is smart enough to know if a process has only been around a few seconds and adjusts the time-window accordingly. Thus you can use this command to immediately see the result.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is a good way to write a long-running loop that's CPU bound without generating a lot of memory traffic or system calls, or using any significant amount of memory or polluting caches so it slows down *other* cores a minimal amount.  ([`stress`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stress) or [`stress-ng`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/stress-ng.1.html) can also do that if you either installed, if you use a simple CPU-stress method.)

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'   # about 3 seconds on 4GHz Skylake
```

It's a counted loop so you can make it exit on its own after a finite amount of time.  (Awk uses FP numbers, so a limit like `2^54` might not be reachable with `i++` due to rounding, but that's way larger than needed for a few seconds to minutes.)

**To run it in parallel, use a shell loop to start it in the background n times**

```
for i in {1..6};do awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}' & done

######     6 threads                      each running about 3 seconds
```

```
$ for i in {1..6};do awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}' & done
[1] 3047561
[2] 3047562
[3] 3047563
[4] 3047564
[5] 3047565
[6] 3047566
$              # this shell is usable.
(wait a while before pressing return)
[1]   Done                    awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'
[2]   Done                    awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'
[3]   Done                    awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'
[4]   Done                    awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'
[5]-  Done                    awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'
[6]+  Done                    awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'
$
```

---

I used `perf` to see what kind of load it put on the CPU: it runs 2.6 instructions per clock cycle, so it's not the most friendly to a hyperthread sharing the same physical core.  But it has a very small cache footprint, getting negligible cache misses even in L1d cache.  And `strace` will show it makes no system calls until exit.

```
$ perf stat -r5 -d awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'

 Performance counter stats for 'awk BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}' (5 runs):

          3,277.56 msec task-clock                #    0.997 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.24% )
                 7      context-switches          #    2.130 /sec                     ( +- 12.29% )
                 1      cpu-migrations            #    0.304 /sec                     ( +- 40.00% )
               180      page-faults               #   54.765 /sec                     ( +-  0.18% )
    13,708,412,234      cycles                    #    4.171 GHz                      ( +-  0.18% )  (62.29%)
    35,786,486,833      instructions              #    2.61  insn per cycle           ( +-  0.03% )  (74.92%)
     9,696,339,695      branches                  #    2.950 G/sec                    ( +-  0.02% )  (74.99%)
           340,155      branch-misses             #    0.00% of all branches          ( +-122.42% )  (75.08%)
    12,108,293,527      L1-dcache-loads           #    3.684 G/sec                    ( +-  0.04% )  (75.10%)
           217,064      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    0.00% of all L1-dcache accesses  ( +- 17.23% )  (75.10%)
            48,695      LLC-loads                 #   14.816 K/sec                    ( +- 31.69% )  (49.90%)
             5,966      LLC-load-misses           #   13.45% of all LL-cache accesses  ( +- 31.45% )  (49.81%)

           3.28711 +- 0.00772 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  0.23% )
```

The most "friendly" to the other hyperthread on an x86 CPU would be a C program like this, which just runs a `pause` instruction in a loop.  (Or portably, a Rust program that runs [`std::hint::spin_loop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hint/fn.spin_loop.html).)  As far as the OS's process scheduler, it stays in user-space (nothing like a `yield()` system call), but in hardware it doesn't take up many resources, letting the other logical core have the front-end for multiple cycles.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
int main(){                    // use atoi(argv[1])*10000ULL as a loop count if you want.
    while(1) _mm_pause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined some of the answers and added a way to scale the stress to all available cpus:

```
#!/bin/bash

function infinite_loop { 
    while [ 1 ] ; do
        # Force some computation even if it is useless to actually work the CPU
        echo $((13**99)) 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    done
}

# Either use environment variables for DURATION, or define them here
NUM_CPU=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null || sysctl -n hw.ncpu)
PIDS=()
for i in `seq ${NUM_CPU}` ;
do
# Put an infinite loop on each CPU
    infinite_loop &
    PIDS+=("$!")
done

# Wait DURATION seconds then stop the loops and quit
sleep ${DURATION}

# Parent kills its children 
for pid in "${PIDS[@]}"
do
    kill $pid
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Just paste this bad boy into the SSH or console of any server running linux.  <s>You can kill the processes manually, but I just shutdown the server when I'm done, quicker.</s>

Edit: I have updated this script to now have a timer feature so that there is no need to kill the processes.

```
read -p "Please enter the number of minutes for test >" MINTEST && [[ $MINTEST == ?(-)+([0-9]) ]]; NCPU="$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)";  ((endtime=$(date +%s) + ($MINTEST*60))); NCPU=$((NCPU-1)); for ((i=1; i<=$NCPU; i++)); do while (($(date +%s) < $endtime)); do : ; done & done
```