# How do I script a "yes" response for installing programs?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I work with [Amazon Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Machine_Image#Amazon_Linux_AMI) instances and I have a couple scripts to populate data and install all the programs I work with, but a couple of the programs ask:

```
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

and pause the install.  I want to auto answer "Y" in all cases, I'm just now sure how to do it.

Comment: The package manager might have a `--noprompt` or `--noconfirm` flag you can use.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

The ['yes' command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)) will echo 'y' (or whatever you ask it to) indefinitely.  Use it as:

```
yes | command-that-asks-for-input
```

or, if a capital 'Y' is required:

```
yes Y | command-that-asks-for-input
```

---

If you want to pass 'N' you can still use `yes`:

```
yes N | command-that-asks-for-input
```

Comment: does this only work with some command supported to use input from yes, doesn't it?
I tried with glance from OpenStack and this not work, I think Expect is more precise for all circumstances

Comment: // , What if you have to enter the full word "yes"?

Comment: Be careful with `yes` as it is known to max out the CPU. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18164007/720665

Comment: Nice. This just made my life substantially easier. :D. Also googling `-y` for bash scripts was HARD.

Comment: @DavidSalamon that's only the case when it's writing to something without limit, like `/dev/null` or STDOUT. Piped to a command, it will only write one line to the pipe each time the receiving command reads one, and will wait otherwise.

Comment: Bevare that `yes` command may fail script if `set -eo pipefail` is enabled.  It may be safer/more portable to use `echo y`

Comment: If you need a password enter, sudo -S: `echo "notsecure" | sudo -S apt-get update`

Comment: Is the enter included in yes?

Answer (score 96):

`echo y | command` should work.

Also, some installers have an "auto-yes" flag. It's `-y` for `apt-get` on Ubuntu.

Comment: I am trying to to do echo "giturl no" |  jspm registry create registry_name jspm-git in my shell script. but it keeps on failing. while entering the giurl. Any idea?

Comment: Another example: In docker-compose there is `-f` (`--force`) flag which works as "auto-yes" for commands that remove something

Comment: How do you "echo Y" recursively in case the prompt asks for a confirmation more than once?

Comment: This is also useful for pip. ex: `echo y | pip uninstall psycopg2-binary`

Comment: This worked for me while using `yes | foo` did not. I needed to run a command like this multiple times in my automation. the `yes | foo` approach broke after one command was run. The `echo Y | foo` approach worked for each line!

Answer (score 21):

You might not have the ability to install Expect on the target server. 
This is often the case when one writes, say, a Jenkins job.

If so, I would consider something like the answer to the following on askubuntu.com:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line

```
printf 'y\nyes\nno\nmaybe\n' | ./script_that_needs_user_input
```

Note that in some rare cases the command does not require the user to press enter after the character. in that case leave the newlines out:

```
printf 'yyy' | ./script_that_needs_user_input
```

For sake of completeness you can also use a here document:

```
./script_that_needs_user_input << EOF
y
y
y
EOF
```

Or if your shell supports it a here string:

```
./script <<< "y
y
y
"
```

Or you can create a file with one input per line:

```
./script < inputfile
```

Again, all credit for this answer goes to the author of [the answer on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/a/338860), lesmana.

Comment: // , Please be sure to upvote the askubuntu.com user @lesmana if you like this answer.

Comment: Is there a way we can also make this use the arrow keys for multiple choice?

Answer (score 14):

You just need to put `-y` with the install command.

For example: `yum install <package_to_install> -y`

Answer (score 7):

Although this may be more complicated/heavier-weight than you want, one very flexible way to do it is using something like [Expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) (or one of the derivatives in another programming language).

Expect is a language designed specifically to control text-based applications, which is exactly what you are looking to do. If you end up needing to do something more complicated (like with logic to actually decide what to do/answer next), Expect is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to just accept defaults you can use:

```
\n | ./shell_being_run
```

Comment: // , How does this mean that you would be accepting defaults?

Comment: In `bash`, `sh` and most system, which I know, you need to `echo` the `\n` otherwise it would not be piped to the next command.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

`echo y | <your_command>`

For example: `echo y | apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

We could also time the sequence, with only `echo` and shell substitution.

The following example dispatch y (yes), wait 3 seconds, answer n (no), wait 3 seconds, and press ENTER:

```
(echo -n "y"; sleep 3; echo -n "n" ; sleep 3; echo -n "\n") | program
```