# How to comfirm automatically when execute a command with python script in centos?

Tags: python, laravel, centos

How to comfirm automatically when execute a command with python script in centos?

For example,
there is a command below,it has a confirmation step:

```
[root@vagrant-prod ~]# php artisan key:generate
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

 Do you really wish to run this command? (yes/no) [no]:
 > yes
```

Now I want to execute above command via a python script:
`auto.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os


def regenerate_key():
    os.system('cd /var/www/laravel_blog && php artisan key:generate')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    regenerate_key()
```

Executing above `auto.py`：

```
[root@vagrant-prod ~]# python3 auto.py
```

It also need to input `yes` manually,I want to comfirm it with above python script,how to do it?

**update:**

```
[root@vagrant-prod laravel_blog]# yes yes | php artisan key:generate
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

Command Cancelled!
```

One yes or two `yes`s have the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I script a "yes" response for installing programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642674/how-do-i-script-a-yes-response-for-installing-programs)

Comment: Did the `yes` Command helped ??

Comment: @Maraboc  yes. it works!

Comment: @Maraboc see my update again,thanks.

Comment: You want that just for the generate command or other commands ??

Comment: @Maraboc system comand like `yes | yum install wget`,it's ok.  above `php artisan key:generate` is php command,the confirmation is defined by php.Here I want that just for this php command.

Comment: ok try it like this `php artisan key:generate --force` it will skip confirmation step ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `yes` command like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os


def regenerate_key():
    os.system('cd /var/www/laravel_blog && yes yes | php artisan key:generate')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    regenerate_key()
```

The command `yes yes` just echos "yes" to the terminal for the duration of the other command. You can confirm this behavior by just typing `yes yes` into a terminal. **Remember that Ctrl+C stops command execution.** So it will enter yes to the prompt and you're gold!

Comment: why two `yes`s?

Comment: Because the yes command alone echos "y" to the terminal. Passing an argument to yes causes it to echo the argument instead.

Comment: Wait so yes cancels it? Weird.

Comment: system comand like `yes | yum install wget`,it's ok.  above `php artisan key:generate` is php command,the confirmation is defined by php.