# what is simplest way to warm up CPU above 90 % usage

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

Sorry if this question seems to be foolish. I want to know how can i put my CPU to work that it's usage increase in arbitrary time. for example i want to turn it over 90 % usage.
if Linux command exists or a simple program to do that it will be a pleasure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I produce high CPU load on a Linux server?](http://superuser.com/q/443406)

Comment: [How to create a CPU spike with a bash command](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2925606/851811) could also be useful.

Comment: that's right Xavi, because i'm not going to load on a server i couldn't find that, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Start running [BOINC](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/) and use your spare capacity to process data for science. You can control how much of your CPU (and GPU) you assign to background processing and you never know - you may be the one to provide the trigger for a cure for cancer or muscular dystrophy.

Keeps you machine occupied doing something useful while you're taking your time punching keys...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following program, compiled in C++

```
int main() {
  for (;;)
    ;
}
```

It will sit in a tight loop and chew up available clock cycles.

Comment: most computers have multiple cpus, this barely does anything to an 8-core 16-thread machine