# How to control CPU usage for particular process?

Tags: c, linux, cpu-usage

I want to control CPU usage through my application, Can anyone help how to achieve that?

For Ex : I want to write a function in that if we pass argument as 150 then cpu usage for that particular process should be 150.

Sorry for not writing code as, I am not sure how to begin with.

So i am not asking for the code but i am asking, If anyone can help me with the logic/how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the Linux kernel already includes features to manage resources for any kind of process; and you can exploit that without writing C code.

To the contrary: you simply want to educate yourself how to use [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups); and then you want to use the concepts behind that with "minimal" efforts on writing custom code on your side.

Do not re-invent the wheel here; as in: your wheel be (most likely) *deficient* compared to what the existing cgroups can do for you **today**!

But even when reading your comment, I don't get why you think you have to implement your **own** solution. If your program needs less than X%; you can't do anything about it anyway. And if it wants more than X; what is the point of creating your own proprietary mechanism of getting there?

Anyhow, maybe the [cpulimit](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2014/11/04/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups) tool could help you getting there.

And, as your "real" problem seems to be: "how to generate CPU load"; well there are plenty of ways to get there, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925606/how-to-create-a-cpu-spike-with-a-bash-command) for example.

Comment: Thank you sir for your valuable reply,
But my question is something different.
I am very much aware with cgroup feature and functionality.

Sir, Basically my question is my application/my program should start CPU usage as provided in argument.

For Ex: if i start while(1); CPU utilization = 100%
if i put sleep(1) in while(1) the CPU utilization = 0-1%.
So what i want is, Whatever the utilization i provide in argument, my application should start using that much cpu.

Comment: Sir, Basically i am preparing a test tool for gerating CPU stress as per requirement, I think cpulimit will help for < 100% but what about > 100%?
How can i generate CPU usage more than 100%? 
I think Creating threads only will help, or is there any other way?