# How to perform stress test on existing linux application

Tags: embedded-linux, load-testing, stress-testing

I have a embedded system with linux platform and I want to perform Stress test and load test on each application. How can I do that?

If I use any bash script (as in below link) or stress tool it increases load on system not on single application

[How to create a CPU spike with a bash command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925606/how-to-create-a-cpu-spike-with-a-bash-command)

Let me know how I can achieve on single application.

Comment: What kind of application are you using? If it is REST API related, you can use this, https://hpwc3po.blogspot.com/2019/11/shell-script-to-simulate-api-requests.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know consume.exe from Windows, you can easily use the 'stress'. It's like  an equivalent of the 'consume'. If you are having trouble using the example below, You can download and install the "stress", it will solve. use the following command:

./stress --cpu 3

It should give you something like >>> stress: info: [18472] dispatching hogs: 3 cpu, 0 io, 0 vm, 0 hdd

Ps: 'Stress' is the name o f the application that runs in Linux, equaly to 'consume' of windows

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It works only for windows . I want to stress a specific application in linux.

Comment: 'Stress' is the name o f the application that runs in Linux, equaly to 'consume' of windows xD, got it? You have to install just like other tool:: apt-get install stress