# Testing if Cluster Autoscaling and overprovisioners works as expected k8s AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

This must sound like a real noob question. I have a cluster-autoscaler and cluster overprovisioner set up in my k8s cluster (via helm). I want to see the auto-scaler and overprovisioner actually kick in. I am not able to find any leads on how to accomplish this.

does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Deployment that runs a container with [a CPU intensive task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925606/how-to-create-a-cpu-spike-with-a-bash-command). Set it initially to a small number of replicas (perhaps < 10) and start increasing the replicas number with:

`kubectl scale --replicas=11 your-deployment`

---

**Edit:**
How to tell the Cluster Autoscaler has kicked in?

There are [three ways](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-can-i-check-what-is-going-on-in-ca-) you can determine what the CA is doing. By watching the CA pods' logs, checking the content of the `kube-system/cluster-autoscaler-status` ConfigMap or [via Events](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-events-are-emitted-by-ca).

Comment: I kind of meant like how would I verify that autoscaler and op have kicked in. apologies for not being clear