# How to run an infinite loop in a Dockerfile where data stats keep increasing?

Tags: bash, docker, shell

I am trying to write a Dockerfile which has an infinite loop with some commands/work inside which will cause the data stats (memory utilization, cpu utilization, PIDs block IO, etc) to increase as the container keeps running. I need this because I am trying to simulate a metric collection process for docker containers so I would like to have some containers running that will keep using resources and show increases when polling 'docker stats'. Currently, I have figured out different tricks for running infinite loops but am not sure how to make the resource usage stats increase. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write a simple shell script to run an infinite loop and use it in your Dockerfile.

Try this [How to create a CPU spike with a bash command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925606/how-to-create-a-cpu-spike-with-a-bash-command)

Comment: I have been trying to write a shell script which is downloading a file from url in an infinite loop and then using it in my Dockerfile with CMD but I can't get it to work. Do you have recommendations on what to put in the shell script to show the resources being increasingly used?